# Creating new XML file while updating existing file

Tags: php, xml

I've read through many of the related questions on this topic and can't seem to find one that highlights saving to 2 separate XML files.

I'm creating a new XML file when an ebook is uploaded. For this example, it would be saved in "new_file.xml". At the same time, I need the new information (`<product>` in this example) added to a full collection file called "full_collection_file.xml" and for that file to be updated. So each time a new ebook is uploaded, "full_collection_file.xml" would have a new `<product>` added to it.

Here's the current structure for the simple "new_file.xml":

```
$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$message = $xml->createElement('ONIXMessage');
$release = $xml->createAttribute('release');
$release->value = '3.0';
$message->appendChild($release);

$header = $xml->createElement('Header');
$FromCompany = $xml->createElement('FromCompany','My Company');
$header->appendChild($FromCompany);
$FromEmail = $xml->createElement('FromEmail','support@ebooks.com');
$header->appendChild($FromEmail);
$SentDate = $xml->createElement('SentDate','201408181805');
$header->appendChild($SentDate);
$message->appendChild($header);

$product = $xml->createElement('Product');
$RecordReference = $xml->createElement('RecordReference','B00BBE4BFE'); 
$product->appendChild($RecordReference);
$NotificationType = $xml->createElement('NotificationType','03');
$product->appendChild($NotificationType);  
$message->appendChild($product);

$xml->appendChild($message);

$xml->save('new_file.xml');
```

This works fine to create the first XML file ("new_file.xml"), but no matter what I try to do inside this same area, I can't seem to properly load and update "full_collection_file.xml". Should I be trying to accomplish these two things separately, instead of simultaneously? Seems redundant, but I was hoping you could have 2 DomDocument files going at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a second `DomDocument` object, and then import the new `Product` node, and append it to the desired location:

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->load('full_collection_file.xml');
$node = $doc->importNode($product, true);
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($node);
```

Obviously, if you don't want the new `<Product>` node right at the document element of `full_collection_file.xml`, you'll want to change that last line accordingly.

Comment: importNode was what I missing; was using about 6 lines to do what that does with 1. Thank you, and I'll update question with full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated from TML:

```
$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$message = $xml->createElement('ONIXMessage');
$release = $xml->createAttribute('release');
$release->value = '3.0';
$message->appendChild($release);

$header = $xml->createElement('Header');
$FromCompany = $xml->createElement('FromCompany','My Company');
$header->appendChild($FromCompany);
$FromEmail = $xml->createElement('FromEmail','support@ebooks.com');
$header->appendChild($FromEmail);
$SentDate = $xml->createElement('SentDate','201408181805');
$header->appendChild($SentDate);
$message->appendChild($header);

$product = $xml->createElement('Product');
$RecordReference = $xml->createElement('RecordReference','B00BBE4BFE'); 
$product->appendChild($RecordReference);
$NotificationType = $xml->createElement('NotificationType','03');
$product->appendChild($NotificationType);  
$message->appendChild($product);

$xml->appendChild($message);
$xml->save('new_file.xml');

$full_xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$full_xml->load('full_collection_file.xml');
$node = $full_xml->importNode($product, true);
$full_xml->documentElement->appendChild($node);
$full_xml->save('full_collection_file.xml');
```